# C's open overwriting file to be opened and fdopen returning NULL

Tags: c, fopen

I'm trying to write a secure version of fopen that prevents the opening of symbolically linked files. Below is my code taken from [here](https://security.web.cern.ch/security/recommendations/en/codetools/c.shtml).

```
/* 
    Secure fopen 
*/
enum { FILE_MODE = 0600 };

FILE *secure_fopen(char *filename, char* mode)
{
    int fd;
    FILE *f;

    unlink(filename);

    if (strncmp(mode, "w", 1) == 0) {
        fd = open(filename, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, FILE_MODE);
    }
    else if (strncmp(mode, "r", 1) == 0) {
        fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL);
    }
    else {
        fd = open(filename, O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, FILE_MODE);
    }

    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("Failed to open the file");
        return NULL; 
    }
    /* Get a FILE*, as they are easier and more efficient than file descriptors */
    f = fdopen(fd, mode);
    if (f == NULL) {
        perror("Failed to associate file descriptor with a stream");
        return NULL; 
    }
    return f;
}
```

There are two issues with this code: one - it's overwriting the file pointed to by filename and two - it's returning NULL, but the NULL file pointer doesn't get caught in the final check:

```
if (f == NULL) {
    perror("Failed to associate file descriptor with a stream");
    return NULL; 
}
```

Does anybody have any insight into way these two things are happening?

Comment: Is it printing "Failed to open the file" ?

Comment: Are you sure about use of `O_EXCL` here ? It will let `open()` fail in cases like mentioned in `man 2 open` --> Ensure  that  this call creates the file: if this flag is speci‐
              fied in conjunction with O_CREAT, and pathname  already  exists,
              __then open() will fail__.

Comment: no. nothing prints.

Comment: Have you bothered to step through it with a debugger?

Comment: given the behavior of O_EXCL when used in conjunction with O_CREAT is there an alternative way to securely open a file?

Comment: @jwdonahue I'm new to C so I haven't used a debugger yet

Comment: That code attempts to delete the specified file without checking the return from `unlink`, but that kind of makes sense; because it doesn't check whether the file exists first. There's only two ways out of the function that could return NULL, both of them print an error message. Step through the code in a debugger.

Comment: @jwdonahue where in the code does it attempt to delete the file? My intention is only to open the file in read or write mode and return the file pointer.

Comment: When you read a piece of code that calls functions you are not familiar with, you should look them up with a google search. What do you think `unlink(filename)` does?

Comment: ... or I often find checking my local manual page to be more convenient.  But one way or another, you need to understand what the functions you're calling actually do.

Comment: Note that the problem the code you drew from is intended to mitigate is, from the linked site, "It is a good idea to check whether a file exists or not before ***creating*** it"  (emphasis added).  Note, too, that the original source contains comments that, had they been retained, might have clued you in to the nature of the problem.

Comment: For standard C and POSIX.1 C functions such as these, the [Linux man pages project](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/dir_all_alphabetic.html) is the most up to date source I know. Each page has a *Conforming to* section you can check to see which standards/systems support each function.

Answer (score 2):

First, `O_CREAT` creates a file if it does not exist, and `O_CREAT|O_EXCL` creates the file and fails if it already exists.

Second, `(strncmp(mode, "w", 1) == 0)` is equivalent to `(mode[0] == 'w')`, which is probably not what you intended. You probably meant `(strchr(mode, "w"))` instead.

Consider the following implementation (a full example program):

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

/* Internal flags used by custom_fopen(): */
#define  FM_R        (1<<0)  /* r, w+: For reading */
#define  FM_W        (1<<1)  /* w, r+: For writing */
#define  FM_TRUNC    (1<<2)  /* w, w+: Truncate */
#define  FM_CREAT    (1<<3)  /* w, r+: Create if necessary */
#define  FM_EXCL     (1<<4)  /* x: Fail if already exists */
#define  FM_APPEND   (1<<5)  /* a: Append */
#define  FM_CLOEXEC  (1<<6)  /* e: Close-on-exec() */
#define  FM_SYMLINK  (1<<7)  /* s: Fail if last path component is a symlink */
#define  FM_RW       (FM_R | FM_W) /* r+, w+ */

FILE *custom_fopen(const char *path, const char *mode)
{
    const char *fdmode;
    int         fm, flags, fd, saved_errno;
    FILE       *ret;

    if (!path || !*path || !mode) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return NULL;
    }

    switch ((strchr(mode, 'r') ? 1 : 0) +
            (strchr(mode, 'w') ? 2 : 0) +
            (strchr(mode, 'a') ? 4 : 0) +
            (strchr(mode, '+') ? 8 : 0)) {
    case 1:  fdmode = "r";  fm = FM_R;                         break;
    case 2:  fdmode = "w";  fm = FM_W  | FM_CREAT | FM_TRUNC;  break;
    case 4:  fdmode = "a";  fm = FM_W  | FM_CREAT | FM_APPEND; break;
    case 9:  fdmode = "r+"; fm = FM_RW | FM_CREAT;             break;
    case 10: fdmode = "w+"; fm = FM_RW | FM_CREAT | FM_TRUNC;  break;
    case 12: fdmode = "a+"; fm = FM_RW | FM_CREAT | FM_APPEND; break;
    default:
        /* Invalid combination of 'r', 'w', 'a', and '+'. */
        errno = EINVAL;
        return NULL;
    }

    if (strchr(mode, 'x')) {
        if (fm & FM_CREAT)
            fm |= FM_EXCL;
        else {
            /* 'rx' does not make sense, and would not work anyway. */
            errno = EINVAL;
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    if (strchr(mode, 'e'))
        fm |= FM_CLOEXEC;

    if (strchr(mode, 's'))
        fm |= FM_SYMLINK;

    /* Verify 'mode' consists of supported characters only. */
    if (strlen(mode) != strspn(mode, "rwa+xesb")) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Map 'fm' to 'flags' for open(). */
    switch (fm & FM_RW) {
    case FM_R:  flags = O_RDONLY; break;
    case FM_W:  flags = O_WRONLY; break;
    case FM_RW: flags = O_RDWR;   break;
    default:
        errno = EINVAL;
        return NULL;
    }
    if (fm & FM_TRUNC)   flags |= O_TRUNC;
    if (fm & FM_CREAT)   flags |= O_CREAT;
    if (fm & FM_EXCL)    flags |= O_EXCL;
    if (fm & FM_APPEND)  flags |= O_APPEND;
    if (fm & FM_CLOEXEC) flags |= O_CLOEXEC;
    if (fm & FM_SYMLINK) flags |= O_NOFOLLOW;

    /* Open the file. If we might create it, use mode 0666 like fopen() does. */
    if (fm & FM_CREAT)
        fd = open(path, flags, 0666);
    else
        fd = open(path, flags);

    /* Failed? */
    if (fd == -1)
        return NULL; /* errno set by open() */

    /* Convert the file descriptor to a file handle. */
    ret = fdopen(fd, fdmode);
    if (ret)
        return ret;

    /* Failed. Remember the reason for the failure. */
    saved_errno = errno;

    /* If we created or truncated the file, unlink it. */
    if (fm & (FM_EXCL | FM_TRUNC))
        unlink(path);

    /* Close the file descriptor. */
    close(fd);

    /* Return, recalling the reason for the failure. */
    errno = saved_errno;
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *handle;

    if (argc != 3 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s PATH MODE\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    handle = custom_fopen(argv[1], argv[2]);
    if (!handle) {
        const int err = errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "custom_fopen(\"%s\", \"%s\") == NULL, errno = %d: %s.\n",
                        argv[1], argv[2], err, strerror(err));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (fclose(handle)) {
        const int err = errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "fclose(custom_fopen(\"%s\", \"%s\")) failed, errno = %d: %s.\n",
                        argv[1], argv[2], err, strerror(err));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("custom_fopen(\"%s\", \"%s\"): Success.\n", argv[1], argv[2]);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L` tells your C library (at least those compatible to GNU C) to expose POSIX.1-2008 features (like [`open()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)).

The behaviour of `r`, `w`, `a`, `r+`, `w+`, and `a+` modes are as described in [`man 3 fopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html). At least one of these must be in `mode`. (The `+` does not need to immediately follow the letter, though.)

The above implementation additionally supports `b` (does nothing, per POSIX), `x` (fail if creating a new file but it already exists), `s` (fail if the filename part of the path is a symlink), and `e` (close the descriptor at exec, not leaking it to child processes).

The first `switch` statement handles the primary mode, ignoring the order of the characters. It essentially checks which of the four characters `rwa+` exist in `mode`, and only accepts the sane combinations. The [`strchr(mode, 'c')`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html) calls return a nonzero pointer (logical true) if and only if `mode` contains `'c'`.

The `if` clause following it detects `x` in the mode. The combination of `x` and `r` is not allowed, because it makes no sense. (POSIX.1 says the behaviour with `open()` with `O_RDONLY | O_EXCL` is undefined.)

The `(strlen(mode) == strspn(mode, "rwa+xesb"))` verifies that `mode` consists only of letters `r`, `w`, `a`, `+`, `x`, `e`, `s`, and `b`; they can be repeated, or in any order.  This check rejects unsupported characters.

The second `switch` statement and `if` clauses map `fm` to `flags`. We do this, because the `O_` constants may not be single bits, which means tests like `(flags & O_RDONLY)`, `(flags & O_WRONLY)`, and `(flags & O_RDWR)` are not reliable, and in fact will not work the way one might expect.  Instead, we use `fm` and our own single-bit `FM_` constants that we can treat as masks, and just map them to corresponding values of `flags` later on.  (Simply put, `fm` tracks the features we want, and we only assign the corresponding set of flags to `flags`, and never *examine* `flags`.)

If we might create the file, we use mode `0666` (`rw-rw-rw-`), as modified by user's `umask`. (Typically, normal users have an umask of `002`, `007`, `022`, or `077`, which result in new files getting modes `0664` (`rw-rw-r--`), `0660` (`rw-rw----`), `0644` (`rw-r--r--`), or `0600` (`rw-------`), respectively.)
This is exactly what `fopen()` does, too.

When we have the open file descriptor, we must still associate it with a stream handle. We do that using [`fdopen()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fdopen.3.html). Note that we decided on the correct `mode` for this call in the first `switch` statement.  If this call succeeds, the stream will "own" the file descriptor, and all we need to do is to return the stream handle `fdopen()` returned.

If `fdopen()` fails, we need to close the file descriptor. We may also decide to remove/unlink the file. The above code removes the file if we are sure it did not exist previously (`e`), or if we truncated it (`w`, `w+`) as then the data it might have contained would be lost anyway.

The test program takes two command-line parameters: a path or a file name, and the mode string. The program does a `custom_fopen(pathorfilename, modestring)` call, and reports the results. (If the `custom_fopen()` call succeeds, it also checks that the corresponding `fclose()` call succeeds, because sometimes issues related to the file descriptor (or incompatible mode flags for the `open()`/`fdopen()` calls) may only be observed at the first operation done, or at stream close fime.

I've only lightly tested the above function and program, and bugs are always a possibility.  If you find a bug or have an issue with the code, let me know in a comment, so I can verify and fix if necessary.